# I want to export pdf to xml with font information as attribute values

Tags: c#, itext, pdfsharp

I want to export pdf to xml with font information lik font-size, font name, font-style, word spacing, letter spacing etc using any Freely available pdf libraries like PDFSharp, ItextSharp.

For example:

<p font-style="10pt", font-style="italic" letter-spacing="somevalue" word-spacing="somevalue">Paragraph text goes here</p>

Is it possible to do using C#? If possible Where can I get related information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open source project PDF Clown might help you. Following is the url to its features page which includes text imports with formatting info. which you can then turn into XElement , XAttribute etc. etc. and/or finally  XMLSerialize into an xml document.

http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/en/projects/clown/features.html

The sourcefourge download is following:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/clown/